# Nginx error_log filter for one server block

Tags: nginx

I want to remove "is forbidden" 403-error messages in my error log from Nginx. Every time someone visits a folder rather than a file, this gets added to the log:

```
2019/04/21 09:57:50 [error] 30368#30368: *1132461 directory index of "/var/www/domain.com/html/assets/js/" is forbidden
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com**

```
server {
    ...

    map $status $only_200 {
        ~^200 0;
        default 1;
    }
    error_log /var/www/domain.com/html/api/logs/nginx-error.vc combined if=$only_200;
}
```

I've tried a lot of combinations like this, but it seems like my syntax is wrong even when copy/pasting. What am I missing?

Comment: You are confusing the access log and the error log. These messages appear in the error log (unless you use a `try_files` directive) and the `if=` parameter only applies to the `access_log` directive.

Comment: As Richard suggested - you can try adding `try_files $uri =404;` and also `log_not_found off;` although this will mute all 404 errors and you might not want that.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I actually already have it on, and it's working great, however it's still letting 403-errors through. In my case, I'm loading the error log using php, so I might just make a filter on my own.

Comment: Okay, then another idea is to define some default index (e.g. `index nothing.txt;`) with a name which will never happen to exist - and this should hopefully convert the 403s into 404s which should be handled by the `try_files` directive.